# How to enable Route only to a page when Auth is successful, if user is not logged in then it will redirect the person to auth page in ReactJS..?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, frontend, web-deployment-project

The problem is when after i login and then i click in the store tab, it still redirects me to the login page always.

This is my App.js file, in here i am using auth context and `isLogin` value to determine if the user is logged in or not.

```
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import CartProvider from "../src/Store/CartProvider";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Headers from "./Headers";
import About from "./About/About";
import Store from "../src/Store/Store";
import Home from "./Home/Home";
import ContactUs from "./ContactUs/ContectUs";
import ProductDetails from "../src/Store/ProductDetails";
import Login from "./Login/Login";
import AuthProvider from "./Login/AuthProvider";
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "./Login/auth-context";

function App() {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
  console.log(authCtx)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AuthProvider>
        <CartProvider>
          <Headers />
          {/* <Switch> */}
            <Route path="/" exact>
              <Redirect to="/home" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/home">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            {console.log(`rerendering app.js`)}
            <Route path="/store">
            {console.log(`rerendering app.js inside route store`)}
          {authCtx.isLogin && <Store />}
          {!authCtx.isLogin && <Redirect to='/auth' />}
          </Route>
            {/* <Route path="/store">
              <Store />
            </Route> */}
            <Route path="/auth">
              <Login />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about">
              <About />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/contactUs">
              <ContactUs />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/product/:productId">
              <ProductDetails />
            </Route>
          {/* </Switch> */}
          <Footer />
        </CartProvider>
      </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my AuthProvider file contatins detail about how am i setting the value of `isLogin`

```
import { useState } from "react"
import AuthContext from "./auth-context"

const AuthProvider = (props) => {
    console.log(`hii`)
    const [token, setToken] = useState(null)
    const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);

    // const isLogin = !!token;
    // let isLogin1 = false
    // console.log(isLogin)

    const loginHandler = (idToken) => {

        setToken(idToken)
        setIsLogin(true)
        console.log(`afer setToken`)
    }

    console.log(`afer loginHandler`)

    const authContext = {

        token: token,
        isLogin: isLogin, 
        login: loginHandler
    }
    console.log(authContext)
    return <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
        {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
}

export default AuthProvider
```

This is my Auth Context file, simple Auth Context file

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({

    token: '',
    isLogin: false, 
    login: (idToken) => {}
});

export default AuthContext;
```

This is my header file, i am not sure but might you may want to have a look. In this file there is `NavLink` which you know changes the url

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import classes from "./Headers.module.css";
import AuthContext from "./Login/auth-context";

const Heading = () => {
  console.log(`headers`)
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext)
    
  return (
    <>
      <ul className={classes.menu}>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/store">Store</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/auth">Login</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/contactUs">Contact US</NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h1 className={classes.heading}>The Generics</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default Heading;
```

This is my login.js file, details regarding when i click on login button and so

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "./auth-context";

const Login = () => {
  const emailInputRef = useRef();
  const passwordInputRef = useRef();

  const history = useHistory();
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

  // useEffect(() => {

  //   console.log(authCtx.isLogin)
  //   if(authCtx.isLogin) {
  //     <Redirect to="/store" />
  //   }
  // }, [authCtx.isLogin])

  const onLoginSubmitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "<Here is my POST request API using firebase as backend>",
        {
          email: enteredEmail,
          password: enteredPassword,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }
      );

      const token = response.data.idToken;
      authCtx.login(token);
      console.log(authCtx.isLogin)
      history.replace('/store')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    console.log(`before redirect to store`);

    // <Redirect to='/store' />
    // history.replace('/store')
    console.log(`inside submit handler`);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={onLoginSubmitHandler}>
        <div>
          <span>Email</span>
          <input type="text" ref={emailInputRef}></input>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>Password</span>
          <input type="text" ref={passwordInputRef}></input>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

From what I can see of the code you shared the issue is caused by the `App` component being the component providing the `AuthContext` value, so it can't use the `AuthContext` itself.

## Solution

Promote the `AuthProvider`  higher in the ReactTree than the `App` component so it can consume and use the `AuthContext` value it provides.

Example

```
<AuthProvider>
  </App />
</AuthProvider>
```

...

```
function App() {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CartProvider>
        <Headers />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/product/:productId">
            <ProductDetails />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/home">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/store">
            {authCtx.isLogin && <Store />}
            {!authCtx.isLogin && <Redirect to='/auth' />}
          </Route>
          <Route path="/store">
            <Store />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/auth">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/contactUs">
            <ContactUs />
          </Route>
          <Redirect from="/" exact to="/home" />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </CartProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```